# Elasticsearch-Hadoop library cannot connect to to docker container

Tags: scala, elasticsearch, apache-spark, docker, elasticsearch-hadoop

I have spark job that reads from Cassandra, processes/transforms/filters the data, and writes the results to Elasticsearch.  I use docker for my integration tests, and I am running into trouble of writing from spark to Elasticsearch.

Dependencies:

```
"joda-time"              % "joda-time"          % "2.9.4",
"javax.servlet"          %  "javax.servlet-api" % "3.1.0",
"org.elasticsearch"      %  "elasticsearch"     % "2.3.2",
"org.scalatest"          %% "scalatest"         % "2.2.1",
"com.github.nscala-time" %% "nscala-time"       % "2.10.0",
"cascading"              %   "cascading-hadoop" % "2.6.3",
"cascading"              %   "cascading-local"  % "2.6.3",
"com.datastax.spark"     %% "spark-cassandra-connector" % "1.4.2",
"com.datastax.cassandra" % "cassandra-driver-core" % "2.1.5",
"org.elasticsearch"      %  "elasticsearch-hadoop"      % "2.3.2" excludeAll(ExclusionRule("org.apache.storm")),
"org.apache.spark"       %% "spark-catalyst"            % "1.4.0" % "provided"
```

In my unit tests I can connect to elasticsearch using a TransportClient to setup my template and index

aka. This works

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("test_reindex").setMaster("local")
  .set("spark.cassandra.input.split.size_in_mb", "67108864")
  .set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", cassandraHostString)
  .set("es.nodes", elasticsearchHostString)
  .set("es.port", "9200")
  .set("http.publish_host", "")
sc = new SparkContext(conf)
esClient = TransportClient.builder().build()
esClient.addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName(elasticsearchHostString), 9300))
esClient.admin().indices().preparePutTemplate(testTemplate).setSource(Source.fromInputStream(getClass.getResourceAsStream("/mytemplate.json")).mkString).execute().actionGet()
esClient.admin().indices().prepareCreate(esTestIndex).execute().actionGet()
esClient.admin().indices().prepareAliases().addAlias(esTestIndex, "hot").execute().actionGet()
```

However when I try to run

```
EsSpark.saveToEs(
  myRDD,
  "hot/mytype",
  Map("es.mapping.id" -> "id", "es.mapping.parent" -> "parent_id")
)
```

I receive this stack trace

```
org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.EsHadoopNoNodesLeftException: Connection error (check network and/or proxy settings)- all nodes failed; tried [[172.17.0.2:9200]] 
at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.NetworkClient.execute(NetworkClient.java:142)
at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.execute(RestClient.java:434)
at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.executeNotFoundAllowed(RestClient.java:442)
at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.exists(RestClient.java:518)
at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.touch(RestClient.java:524)
at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestRepository.touch(RestRepository.java:491)
at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestService.initSingleIndex(RestService.java:412)
at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestService.createWriter(RestService.java:400)
at org.elasticsearch.spark.rdd.EsRDDWriter.write(EsRDDWriter.scala:40)
at org.elasticsearch.spark.rdd.EsSpark$$anonfun$saveToEs$1.apply(EsSpark.scala:67)
at org.elasticsearch.spark.rdd.EsSpark$$anonfun$saveToEs$1.apply(EsSpark.scala:67)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
16/08/08 12:30:46 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 2, localhost): org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.EsHadoopNoNodesLeftException: Connection error (check network and/or proxy settings)- all nodes failed; tried [[172.17.0.2:9200]] 
at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.NetworkClient.execute(NetworkClient.java:142)
at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.execute(RestClient.java:434)
at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.executeNotFoundAllowed(RestClient.java:442)
at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.exists(RestClient.java:518)
at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.touch(RestClient.java:524)
at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestRepository.touch(RestRepository.java:491)
at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestService.initSingleIndex(RestService.java:412)
at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestService.createWriter(RestService.java:400)
at org.elasticsearch.spark.rdd.EsRDDWriter.write(EsRDDWriter.scala:40)
at org.elasticsearch.spark.rdd.EsSpark$$anonfun$saveToEs$1.apply(EsSpark.scala:67)
at org.elasticsearch.spark.rdd.EsSpark$$anonfun$saveToEs$1.apply(EsSpark.scala:67)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I can verify using 'docker network inspect bridge that it is trying to connect to the correct ip address.

```
docker network inspect bridge
[
{
    "Name": "bridge",
    "Id": "ef184e3be3637be28f854c3278f1c8647be822a9413120a8957de6d2d5355de1",
    "Scope": "local",
    "Driver": "bridge",
    "EnableIPv6": false,
    "IPAM": {
        "Driver": "default",
        "Options": null,
        "Config": [
            {
                "Subnet": "172.17.0.0/16",
                "Gateway": "172.17.0.1"
            }
        ]
    },
    "Internal": false,
    "Containers": {
        "0c79680de8ef815bbe4bdd297a6f845cce97ef18bb2f2c12da7fe364906c3676": {
            "Name": "analytics_rabbitmq_1",
            "EndpointID": "3f03fdabd015fa1e2af802558aa59523f4a3c8c72f1231d07c47a6c8e60ae0d4",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:04",
            "IPv4Address": "172.17.0.4/16",
            "IPv6Address": ""
        },
        "9b1f37c8df344c50e042c4b3c75fcb2774888f93fd7a77719fb286bb13f76f38": {
            "Name": "analytics_elasticsearch_1",
            "EndpointID": "fb083d27aaf8c0db1aac90c2a1ea2f752c46d8ac045e365f4b9b7d1651038a56",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
            "IPv4Address": "172.17.0.2/16",
            "IPv6Address": ""
        },
        "ed0cfad868dbac29bda66de6bee93e7c8caf04d623d9442737a00de0d43c372a": {
            "Name": "analytics_cassandra_1",
            "EndpointID": "2efa95980d681b3627a7c5e952e2f01980cf5ffd0fe4ba6185b2cab735784df6",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:03",
            "IPv4Address": "172.17.0.3/16",
            "IPv6Address": ""
        }
    },
    "Options": {
        "com.docker.network.bridge.default_bridge": "true",
        "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_icc": "true",
        "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_ip_masquerade": "true",
        "com.docker.network.bridge.host_binding_ipv4": "0.0.0.0",
        "com.docker.network.bridge.name": "docker0",
        "com.docker.network.driver.mtu": "1500"
    },
    "Labels": {}
}
]
```

I am running everything locally on a macbook/osx.  I am at a loss for why I can connect to the docker container using the TransportClient and through my browser, but the function EsSpark.saveToES(...) always fails.

Comment: Does your app names same?

Comment: Can you try to set the `es.nodes.wan.only` parameter to true?

Answer (score 2):

By setting

```
.config("es.nodes.wan.only", "true")
```

can solve this issue

> es.nodes.ingest.only
>
> (default false) Whether to use Elasticsearch
>   ingest nodes only. When enabled, elasticsearch-hadoop will route all
>   of its requests (after nodes discovery, if enabled) through the ingest
>   nodes within the cluster. The purpose of this configuration setting is
>   to avoid incurring the cost of forwarding data meant for a pipeline
>   from non-ingest nodes; Really only useful when writing data to an
>   Ingest Pipeline (see es.ingest.pipeline above).